# What does "if of" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Classes may occasionally cross these age ranges if of academic benefit

Does it mean "Classes may exceed the age ranges if the class is considered to have academic benefit to do so"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words:

> Classes may occasionally cross these age ranges if (they are) of academic benefit.

where "they" refers to the "classes".